# How to make a block of prices for all the same padding

Tags: html, css

Faced with the problem the block of my prices has different indents everywhere. This is due to the length of the text (product name). How to make a block of prices for all the same markup. How can I do it? Help me, please. At least a small example.

[image: example]
**html**

```
<div class="product_grid">
    <div class="product_section">
        <div>
            <a href="#">
                <div>
                    <img class="product_image" src="#">

                    <div class="product_text">
                        <div class="product_name">Name</div>
                        <div class="product_price_block">
                            <div class="product_price empty">1200 &#8381;</div>
                            <div class="product_price">1800 &#8381;</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button class="add_to_cart">Add to cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.product_grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(230px, 1fr));
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    grid-column-gap: 3%;
    padding: 8px;
}

.product_grid > * {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}

.product_price_block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    margin-top: 3rem;

}

.add_to_cart {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
}

.product_image {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try giving the price block or product name a height.

Comment: You can give a `height:??px;` value to the product name

Comment: Since you are using flex you can stretch container items to the same height and use margin bottom auto to the product name and that will position everything in the same consistent place even if there was 3 lines of text

Comment: Indeed. There is **NO** CSS method of aligning elements or equalising heights of elements that do not share a parent.

Comment: You might need to apply stretch to a few of the containers so that everything stretches to the outer container. I have used this in the past for similar problems

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of what i was meaning: https://jsfiddle.net/nb56p048/ - all of the lower section aligns in the same place. You would have to change the structure of your layout to make it work more easily. I also use bootstrap. So use a lot of bootstrap classes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can fix the product name div height.
Try this:-

```
.product_name{
   height: 30px;
}
```